# How do I change the data type of a dataframe when converting it to HTML with to_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas

Since the columns of a pandas DataFrame (or a Series) are homogeneously of type unless I add dtype='object', I wondered how could I change the dtype of certain rows when using pandas.DataFrame.to_html(). For example I would like that the rows 1-3 are displayed as int, whereas the rows 4-5 should be displayed as floats. From the docs of to_html I understand that I have some options like CSS styles. However, I don't know how to do it with the function..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6.0],
'Column2': [2, 3, 3, 2, 1.0]})
```

This gives me for example:

```
Column1 Column2
0   2.0 2.0
1   3.0 3.0
2   4.0 3.0
3   5.0 2.0
4   6.0 1.0
```

So I want to use this function (to_html) in a way so that I get

```
df_html = df.to_html(*options*)
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df_html)

Column1 Column2
0   2   2
1   3   3
2   4   3
3   5.0 2.0
4   6.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, even though it's a bit `ad-hoc`:

```
df  = df.astype(str)
sty = lambda x : str(int(float(x)))
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df.index<3, col] = df.loc[df.index<3, col].apply(sty)
```

Basically, you convert everything to `string` and then apply specific formatting depending on the row number.